# How to develop fragment order in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have few fragments: A, B, C, D.
Basic flow is: A->B->C->D
If user go back: D->B->A

Actually I have few different flow and I should create flow when application starts. What is the best way to do it without any library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FragmentManager transactions is your best bet.

please have a look [here (official doc)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions)

Answer (score 0):

When you are going from `fragment C` to `D` use following code:
It will remove `fragment C` from `backstack`. So that if you are going back from `D`, it will not find `fragment C` in the `stack` and It will directly go to `fragment B`.

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

or

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack()
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code when FragmentTransaction from fragment C to D

```
.........
  fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
  fragmentTransaction.commit()
```